# JEST throws error: Cannot use import statement outside a module in REact app made with CRA, with TS; I am afterew solution already but not work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have read many possible answers, but none works in my case (so please be no surprised - my config files are now overfilled)
The problem is thrown on line:

```
import axios from "axios";
```

Here are config files

```
//jest.config.ts
import type { Config } from "@jest/types";

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
    roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
        "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/jest-config/style-mock.js",
        "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!axios)",
        "node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|react-native-vector-icons)/)",
    ],

    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"],
    testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(tsx|jsx)?$",
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    collectCoverage: false,
    collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
    },
    globals: {
        "ts-jest": {
            isolatedModules: true,
        },
    },
};

export default config;
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "perfectcolors",
    "version": "0.1.2",
    "homepage": "https://kiszuriwalilibori.github.io/perfectcolors",
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
        "@mui/material": "^5.11.3",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
        "@types/node": "^16.18.11",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
        "axios": "^1.2.2",
        "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "notistack": "^2.0.8",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-uuid": "^2.0.0",
        "redux": "^4.2.0",
        "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
        "typescript": "^4.9.4",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191"
    }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] };
```

babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "modules": "commonjs"
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

Really, I do not know what is going on. I can even believe that some measures I took are conflicting with others, but, really, it was rather copy-paste action.

Answer (score 0):

update :

```
"module": "esnext"
```

to :

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

in your `tsconfig.json`